# Shapeless and gremlin scala: How do I return the result of a call to `as`?

Tags: scala, gremlin, shapeless

So, I am calling this function `as` (from `gremlin-scala`):

```
case class GremlinScala[End, Labels <: HList](traversal: GraphTraversal[_, End]) {
  def as(name: String, moreNames: String*)(implicit p: Prepend[Labels, End :: HNil]) =
    GremlinScala[End, p.Out](traversal.as(name, moreNames: _*))
}
```

It is defined here: https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala/blob/master/gremlin-scala/src/main/scala/gremlin/scala/GremlinScala.scala#L239

It takes an implicit Prepend argument, which I am not sure I understand. I know that `gremlin-scala` uses its HList to keep track of which points in the query `as` is called, so that later when `select` is called it knows which points in the traversal to return.

This is the key: `as` appends to that HList. Or prepends apparently, as the case may be.

This works fine in general code, but now I want to write a function that calls `as` and returns its result. This is where I am stuck: what is the signature of the return value of this function?

Finally, I have added an implicit param to my function, but I fear I have just chased the problem up a level. Here is what I have so far:

```
case class AsOperation[A, In <: HList](step: String) extends Operation {
  def operate(g: GremlinScala[A, In]) (implicit p: Prepend[In, ::[A, HNil]]): GremlinScala[A, p.Out] = {
    g.as(step)
  }
}
```

This makes it compile, but I still can't use this function! Whenever I call it, it complains to me that

```
could not find implicit value for parameter p: shapeless.ops.hlist.Prepend[In,shapeless.::[A,shapeless.HNil]]
```

How do I write a function that returns the result of `as`, and what is its signature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you explain correctly, the reason we use prepend is to keep the types of the steps labelled with `as`. It's keeping them in the reverse order since it's easier to process on both sides: for capturing and replaying.

So the `implicit p: Prepend[Labels, End :: HNil]` is prepending the type at the current step so that we have it captured in the second type parameter (and can use it in later steps, e.g. `select`).

As far as I can see you're doing exactly the right thing, and it actually works... for me anyway :)

This compiles:

```
import gremlin.scala._
import shapeless.{HNil, ::}
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory
def graph = TinkerFactory.createModern.asScala
val gs1: GremlinScala[Vertex, Vertex :: HNil] = graph.V().as("a")
val gs2: GremlinScala[Vertex, Vertex :: HNil] = AsOperation("someLabel").operate(graph.V())
```

Comment: You are right! This does compile and work. It turns out my issue is one level higher, where I am using a Poly2 in a RightFold to apply a series of operations like this. I will make a new question for this issue, thank you for answering! (love gremlin-scala by the way, thanks for writing : )

Comment: Okay, new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754229/scala-gremlin-scala-hlists-poly2-rightfold-and-a-missing-implicit-prepend